# bindParam or binValue will not work

Tags: pdo

Hi It seems that both bindParam or bindValue methods will not work.

Please advise. I tried to bind the $dbname to dbtest. It does not seem to work!

bindParam

```
$dbname = "test1";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare('use :dbtest');
$stmt->bindParam(':dbtest', $dbname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$firephp->fb($stmt); 
try
{   $stmt->execute();
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare('select database()');
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $firephp->warn("Attempting to use selected database is successful.");
}
```

bindValue

```
$dbname = "test1";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare('use :dbtest');
$stmt->bindValue(':dbtest', $dbname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$firephp->fb($stmt); 
try
{   $stmt->execute();
    $stmt=$dbh->prepare('select database()');
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $firephp->warn("Attempting to use selected database is successful.");
    $firephp->fb($count);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [native prepared statements won't work for identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991422/285587)
Second, there is no point in having dynamically bound databases. They are supposed to be constant.

So, select your database in **DSN** and then use bindValue to bind *values* in the query.

Comment: I will not use bindValue or bindParam for any items in $DSN. Not worth fighting against.